# Problem with VSOME/IP: I can't complete CMake

Tags: cmake, googletest

I would like to `cmake` on the first step of my `vsomeip` build. However, I get an error where:

```
GTEST_ROOT is not defined. For building the tests the variable
GTEST_ROOT has to be defined. Tests can not be built.
```

I am an amateur in this subject, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

This repository depends on GTest as mentioned [here](https://github.com/GENIVI/vsomeip#dependencies) in the documentation. The CMake attempts to find the GTest source code locally and build a static library of GTest. So, you should add the `GTEST_ROOT` directory when calling `cmake` using the `-D` definition flag:

```
cmake -DGTEST_ROOT=/path/to/your/gtest/dir ..
```